# href but no url afterwards?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a php script that outputs a link element within a list element depending on certain conditions being met, the code is as follows:

```
    global $wpdb;

    function currentURL() {

        $pageURL = 'http';
        if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
        $pageURL .= "://";
        if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        } else {
            $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        }
        return $pageURL;}

    $getUrl = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_name,option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl' ");

    $url = $geturl->option_value;

    $getData = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT post_title,guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = 'page' ");

    echo "<ul id=\"mainNavInnerContainer\">"; 

    if(currentURL() == $url){
    echo "<li><a href=\"" . $url . "\" id=\"current\">home</a></li>";}

    else{ echo "<li><a href=\"" . $url . "\">home</a></li>"; }
```

The problem I'm having is that when I view the element in source code view in my browser i get the following:

```
<a href>Home</a>
```

I'm really confused as to why this is, and was hoping that anyone else would have any idea why.

**EDIT**
I was able to use a foreach loop to put the value in my $url variable but is this good practice? Because I know that the query in $getUrl will always return one row, but still this method seems pretty error prone. Here is the revised $url variable code:

```
        foreach($getUrl as $urlResult){
        $url = $urlResult->option_value;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add to top of code `error_reporting(E_ALL);`
2. add check:

   ```
   $getUrl = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT option_name,option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'siteurl' ");    
       $url = $geturl->option_value;
   var_dump($url);
   ```

Comment: Well you certainly helped me narrow down one idiotic bug, I wasnt using a capital U in my $getUrl variable, but a var_dump() of $url still returns NULL, I also did a var_dump of $getUrl and it does return one row so I'm confident that part is working.

Comment: return 1 row with what? with `$row['option_value']` or `$rows = array($row['option_value'])` ? then may be you need to do like this `$url = $geturl[0]->option_value;` ?

Comment: Fantastic! The wpdb object I was using to query the wordpress table returned the results in the form of an array, makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you view the source of a page, some browsers (Firefox is one, I believe) show you there source they're rendering, not the source you sent them. If the attribute has no value specified, the browser may chose to display it like this, with the attribute present but without a value.

Comment: So what your saying is my script is not setting a value?

Comment: I think it's probably not; I'm not familiar enough with the software to be sure. I just wanted to point out not to trust the source your browser displays.